# Inversing a function

Tags: calculus, inverse

I'm having some problems calculating the inverse of this function:

$f(u,v)=(u+v,v-u^2)$, its domain is $D=\{(u,v)$ in $\Bbb R^2 : u>0\}$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the inverse function $f^{-1}(a,b)$, you have to solve
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
u+v = a\\
v-u^2 = b
\end{array}\right.$$
$$\begin{align}
(u +v) - (v-u^2) =& a-b\\
u^2 + u - a + b =& 0\\
u =& \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(a-b)}}2\\
v =& a-\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(a-b)}}2\\
f^{-1}(a,b) =& \left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(a-b)}}2,a-\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(a-b)}}2\right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Setting $x=u+v$ and $y=v-u^2$, we find that

$$u=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4(x-y)}}{2}$$

Note that the constraint $u \gt0$ implies that we take the plus sign above and constrain $x \gt y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to solve the simultaneous equations of $(u, v)$
$$
x=u+v \qquad y=v-u^2
$$